# Printing on Solaris

Tags: solaris, printing, ipp

I have set up a network IPP printer on Solaris 10, but when I send a printing job to the queue, I received `failed to commit job (2-0): queue disabled` error, any idea why?

```
# lpstat -t
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for printer: ipp://172.16.138.20/printers/DA1D9C
printer not accepting requests since October 13, 2016 12:04:37 AM PDT
        new destination
printer printer is idle. enabled since October 13, 2016 12:14:51 AM PDT. available.
# lp -d printer localhost.err
printer: failed to commit job (2-0): queue disabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the print client, stop further queuing of print requests to the print server.

```
 # reject printer-name
```

On the print client, send an “are you there?” request to the print server.

```
 print-client# ping print-server
 print-server is alive.
```

If you receive the message print-server `not available`, you might have a network problem.

After you fix the above problem, allow new print requests to be queued.

```
 # accept printer-name
```

If necessary, re-enable the printer.

```
 # enable printer-name
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem of committing jobs to the queue.

Comment: Now I use lp to send print jobs and it shows "request id is printer-name-6 (1 file(s))

Comment: But the printing is not carried out, any idea why? I am able to ping the server IP, so it's not a network issue.

Comment: Do I have to install the printer driver on the server first?